# how to tell PyCharm to run pytest on test files not doctests

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, doctest

In the test suite of a module, some `test_foo.py` files have helper functions containing doctests patterns in their docstrings.  This causes PyCharm to offer `Debug 'Doctests in test_foo'` when selecting a function inside that file and trying via context-menu to debug just that function. It doesn't matter whether that function is before any actual `test_...()` function or at the end of the file, the mere presence of a single docstring with a doctests pattern causes PyCharm to exhibit this behavior.

If I just change all the `>>> ...` into `/>>> ...` for example (to cripple the doctests search), then the behavior is as expected for a test file: context-menu on a function offers `Debug 'pytest for test_foo.test_function'`.

Is there a way to tell PyCharm to prioritize `pytest` over `doctests` if both are feasible?

Comment: I don't think there is. I had similar problems and just added a configuration for pytest manually in this case.

Comment: Yes, I've done that too, but got frustrated to manually add a config for each function that I want to debug. De-fanging the doctests seems to work fine. Could be done by a script too: `perl -pi -e 's/(?<!#)>>>/#>>>/' tests/**/*.py` to cripple doctests, and the opposite to restore them. Sigh.

Comment: That's probably your best bet at the moment. I did a search for something else at the time, including checking PyCharm's source code IIRC,  and didn't find anything. You could file an issue with JetBrains, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **Run -> Run ...** menu option. The popup should have multiple choices including pytest

[image]

Please vote for the corresponding ticket in PyCharm's issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35985

Comment: excellent work-around! Your ticket on youtrack describes exactly the desired behavior for the quick context-menu.

Comment: FYI, we just fixed it by extracting the helper functions with doctests to a separate file...